# Javascript image load and display

Tags: javascript, image, dom-events

I have a web page that shows an image and two arrows, with Javascript.

When the right arrow is clicked, the index increments and a new image should be loaded.
When the left arrow is clicked, the index decrements and a new image should be loaded.

I added some alerts to the code which shows that the index is incremented, but the new image is still not displayed. I would appreciate pointers on what's wrong with the code.

Only the initial image is always shown and it's not updated. The link change colors and the alerts are displayed.

```
   <html>
    <head>
     <title> Gallery</title>
    </head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var rightTarget;
        var leftTarget;
        var index = 516;       

        function rightLinkClicked(e) {
            rightTarget = e.target;
            rightTarget.style.color = "green";
            leftTarget.style.color = "black";
            index = index +1;
            alert ("right1")
        var img;
            img=document.getElementsByTagName('img');
            img.src="pics/IMG_0" + index + ".JPG";
            alert ("right2 - index = IMG_0" + index + ".JPG")
            }

function leftLinkClicked(e) {
leftTarget = e.target;
leftTarget.style.color = "red";
rightTarget.style.color = "black";
    if (index >516) {
index = index -1;
}
var img;
    img=document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    img.src="pics/IMG_0" + index + ".JPG"
    alert ("left - index = "+ index)
 }

function addListeners() {
var rightLink = document.getElementById("rightlinkid");
    rightLink.addEventListener('click', rightLinkClicked, false);

    var leftLink = document.getElementById("leftlinkid");
    leftLink.addEventListener('click', leftLinkClicked, false);
}
window.addEventListener('load', addListeners, false);
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <a id="leftlinkid">Left Link
      <img src="icons/left.gif"; alt="left arrow" title="">
   </a>

 <div id="myimg">       
  <img id="img" src="pics/IMG_0516.JPG"; alt="start arrow" title="" width="640" height="480">
 </div>

    <a id="rightlinkid">Right Link
   <img src="icons/right.gif"; alt="right arrow" title="">
   </a>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: The posters have you on the right track... I think you want to use document.getElementById('img') because that will give you the middle image which is the one you want to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `getElementsByTagName` which returns a collection of DOM elements, which is not the same as your single image. You should do

```
img = getElementById('img');
```

Answer (score 0):

The code `img=document.getElementsByTagName('img');` returns a collection.  You need to specify which images' source you want to modify, like `img[index + 1].src = ...`.  I think you will want to use `index + 1` so that it doesn't start counting with the first image (the left arrow).  A better solution might be to give all of your images the same class name and find by class (`document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');`).